# Pass user to telephone dialler, then return when call is done?

Tags: android

My app successfully sends a user to the dialler, passing through the phone number so the user can easily make calls from my app.

Is there any way to set things up so the user is automatically returned to my app once they end the call? They are being returned to another activity within the dialler app and that's not a good experience for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PhoneStateListener` to detect call events, that is the only way I guess. There is a fat chance that your application may be given the boot, to recover resources, so be ready for that

You should detect the transition from `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` to `CALL_STATE_IDLE`